# Command to see if a script was initiated

Tags: scripts, sleep, wireless

When waking up from sleep my laptop immediately connects to the wlan after I run the command `iwlist eth1 scanning` in the terminal.

I tried to add the command to

```
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.de/55NetworkManager
```

and to

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_Grub-common
```

but no joy.

Is there a command that will give you a feedback that the script was initiated, so I can be sure that the script is running but not working as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a line like the following near the begin of the script

```
echo "Starting $0 at time $(date)" >>/var/log/mylog
```

then look at the content of the log file.